# Swapping the parameters of overloaded arithmetic operators

Tags: c++

Say I define a struct, and overload the product operator such that I can multiply objects with a number.

```
struct myStruct
{
myStruct(int a): num(a) {}
int num;
};

myStruct operator*(myStruct A, int b)
{
A.num *= b;
return A;
}
```

Is there any way to make the program understand I'd also like to be able to do int*myStruct without having to copy-paste the overload statement?

Comment: Doesn't A get copied automatically if I don't pass it by reference?

Comment: You're totally right. I misread it as non-const reference, my bad.

Comment: You currently have an implicit conversion from `int` to `myStruct`. That's often error-prone, but allows you here to write `myStruct operator*(myStruct, myStruct)` which will convert either argument from an integral type to `myStruct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to provide both overloads. But you can get rid of the code duplication by using a public member function. Or even better, provide `operator*=` (thanks to @dyp for pointing that out).

For example:

```
struct myStruct {
    myStruct(int a): num(a) {}
    int num;

    myStruct& operator*=(int b) {
        num *= b;
        return *this;
    }
};

// Now you have the minimal amount of code duplication in both overloads
myStruct operator*(myStruct A, int b) {
    return A *= b;
}

myStruct operator*(int a, myStruct B) {
    return B *= a;
}
```

**Note:** Several others already pointed out that your class `myStruct` currently defines an *implicit conversion* via it's non-explicit constructor. So if you'd like to keep this conversion (which I wouldn't recommend), you could actually define a single operator for all cases:

```
myStruct operator*(myStruct a, myStruct b) {
    return a *= b;
}
```

Comment: The implicit conversion is just because I tried coming up with an example that's as simple as possible. Thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: @RobVerheyen oh I see, well I thought I'd add it so that everything discussed is included in a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/utility/operators.htm) library. Derive your class from `boost::multipliable<myStruct, int>`. Then you just need to implement `operator*=(int)` in your class, and Boost will automatically give you the implementation of both directions of `operator*`.

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

struct myStruct : boost::multipliable<myStruct, int>
{
    myStruct(int a): num(a) {}
    int num;

    myStruct &operator *=(int x) {
        num *= x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual plan is to make `+=` a member, because the left has to be an object of your class for that anyway; and use a free function for `+` so that conversions can apply to both sides.

```
struct myStruct
{
    myStruct(int a): num(a) {}
    int num;

    myStruct &operator+=(myStruct b) { num += b.num; return *this; }
};

myStruct operator+(myStruct a, myStruct b) { return a += b; }
```

You have a converting constructor defined so you don't need to provide duplicates of every operator.

Comment: Any reason you use addition instead of multiplication?